# IIS 7 with asp.net : debug writeline does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a simple asp.net application. I want to write in the output console of visual studio in debug mode. I've been using this code for a long time `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello");`.

When I run my web application with IIS Express, it works perfectly well.

When I run it with IIS, nothing appears.

How can I write in the output console with IIS ?

**Edit** : trying to use Trace which is better, here is the code i put in the Application_Start method of my Global.asax, but still not working :

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Trace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It provides a versatile interface to log the execution of your application.

You have to register a listener when your app starts (this can be in various places, depending on your application):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

Then you can use `Trace.WriteLine("Logging to output window");` to log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Trace seems to be more relevant. It doesn't work either however (nothing appears).

Comment: Can you share the type of application you are creating, so I can try to recreate and figure out why it doesn't work?

Comment: Actually it's a MVC web application. I think it's suggested when you create a asp.net project under visual studio. Then choose "IIS Local" in YourProject->Properties->Web->Servers

Comment: Do you have the tracing feature installed? Look for the windows features menu and make sure it is ticked [like so](http://imgur.com/a/3VlL8).

Comment: I didn't have it, i installed it, rebooted my computer and still not working ... I only have the outputs from w3wp.exe

Comment: Hmmm... Can you edit your post to include the code where you register the listener and where you use it?

Comment: Ok it works when i put the listener in the Startup.cs (created by OWIN, that i use too) file and not in the Global.asax file. I hate C#.